# How to track GA events with jQuery on Angularjs site?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am trying to send Google Analytics events if a menu element is clicked. The website that I am tracking is built with Angularjs and I am using jQuery to write the script to fire the events.

The menu has an option to click and collapse the menu it also have main elements that are available through a drop down menu.

My script works fine up until the collapse menu option is clicked and after that only the main elements sends GA events and not the events put on the drop down elements. The same is true when clicking back to the normal menu appearance.

Any ideas how to make this work? Can I somehow see what view that is loaded with jQuery and restart code from there?

```
    window.onload = function(){
// The selector is all main elements in the menu 
    $sJQ(MainElements).on('click',function(){
        $sJQ(SubElements).on('click',function(e){
        if($(this).attr('href') === '/MainElement/') {
        ga('send', 'event', 'Category1', 'Action1', 'Label1');
        } 

    });

// The selector is all subelements in the menu 
    $sJQ(SubElements).on('click',function(e){
        if($(this).attr('href') === '/SubElement/') {
            ga('send', 'event', 'Category2', 'Action2', 'Label2');
            e.stopPropagation();
        } 
    });
// The selector is all subelements in the menu 
        $sJQ(selectorCollapsedSubElement).on('click',function(e){
        if($(this).attr('href') === '/SubElement/') {
            ga('send', 'event', 'Category2', 'Action2', 'Label2');
            e.stopPropagation();
        } 
    });
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you used angulartics?

Comment: I haven't used it because we would prefer not to use a plugin. Is angulartics commonly viewed as the best practice when tracking angular sites or could I also use plain jQuery?